# Why aren't the lines from a file being read added to my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

The below code was written to take two files, find the values that are not duplicates, and output them to another file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

//keeps only uniques
//remove all values that are duplicates
public class dupeCleaner {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String fileA = "Testing1.txt";
        String fileB = "Testing2.txt";
        String[] uniques=clean(fileA,fileB);
        writeFile("file.txt",uniques);
    }
    public static String[] clean(String fileA, String fileB){
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> cleaned = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] list1 = readFile(fileA);
        String[] list2 = readFile(fileB);
        boolean[] firstList = new boolean[list1.length];
        for(int k = 0; k < list1.length;k++){
            firstList[k]=checkDupe(list1[k],list2);
        }
        for(int k = 0; k< list1.length;k++){
            if(firstList[k]){
                cleaned.add(list1[k]);
                System.out.println(list1[k]);
            }
        }
        String[] finalList = new String[cleaned.size()];
        finalList=cleaned.toArray(new String[cleaned.size()]);
        return finalList;
    }
    public static void writeFile(String fileName, String[] list){
        try{
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName,true));
        for(String k: list){
            bw.write(k+"\r\n");
            bw.close();
        }
        }catch(IOException e){
        }
    }
    public static boolean checkDupe(String var, String[] list){
        for(String k : list){
            if(k.equals(var)){
                System.out.println("true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("false");
        return false;
    }
    public static String[] readFile(String fileName){
        ArrayList<String> vars = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                vars.add(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        System.out.println(vars.get(5));
        String[] list = vars.toArray(new String[vars.size()]);
        return list;
    }
}
```

The problem lies with the static method readFile, I don't understand why System.out.println(vars.get(5)); returns an IndexOutOfBoundsException, all the code makes sense to me and the file is definitely being read (there's 100 lines in the first file for example and if I just output the String line it all prints in console).

Would anyone be able to shed light on my problem?

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I'm like 99.9% sure that the file doesn't exist, that the `new FileReader(fileName)` throws an `IOException` to that effect, and that your code catches and **ignores** that exception, such that `vars` is an empty list. **DO NOT IGNORE EXCEPTIONS** They are there for a reason, and have something useful to say, such as: *Your code is not working correctly.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `bw.close` statement out of the `for` loop. What you are doing is writing a line to the file and closing the `Writer` which will write just the first string to the file.

```
try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName,true));){

    for(String k: list){
        bw.write(k+"\r\n");      
    }
}catch(IOException e){
    //Handle exception
}
```

Comment: The `close()` call does not belong inside the `catch` block.

Comment: However, get into the habit of splitting the initializations, one for the `FileWriter` and another for the `BufferedWriter`. If the enclosing object fails during initialization, the wrapped object will potentially not be closed (not in the case of `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter`, but others).

Comment: Ah, that's a nice thing to note, thank you, appreciate it mate. But it's not quite the problem I'm trying to tackle right now, my problem right now is  when I add variables to my ArrayList it doesn't seem to be adding in at all :/ so when I wrote   System.out.println(vars.get(5)); it came out with an index exception

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your code is not keeping the unique values, it's keeping the duplicates. Your text files probably doesn't have enough duplicates and that's why you're getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Change the condition in the `clean()` method to:

```
if (!firstList[k])
```

The second problem you'll encounter is that you're trying to write to a closed file because you close it in a foreach loop. Remove the `bw.close()` statement from the loop in `writeFile()`:

```
for (String k : list) {
    bw.write(k + "\r\n");      
}
```